# JQuery does not work in Firefox but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm having trouble with jQuery and Mozzila Firefox. 
Everything is working just fine in Chrome, but somehow Firefox does not see jQuery.

This is how I call jQuery

```
 <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/datepicker.js"></script>
```

And this is where it fails (error is: ReferenceError: $ is not defined):

```
 <script>
        function ajax_check(){

            var id = $("#xml_select").val(); // this is the line where I get error

             $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax_check.php?id="+id,
                    success: function(response) {

                        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

                       //console.log( JSON.stringify(result['ncp'].replace('"','')) );

                       var ncp = JSON.stringify(result['ncp']);
                       var id = JSON.stringify(result['id']);


                       $("#racun").val(ncp.substring(1,12));

                       $("#id_podnosilac").val(id.substring(1,5));
                    }, 
                  });

        }
</script>
```

Please help, what could be causing this?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Maybe just FF browser's cache issue... Because otherwise, your code would work.

Comment: make full request Ctrl +F5

Comment: You should mention the error too!

Comment: @RayonDabre `(error is: ReferenceError: $ is not defined)`

Comment: try with jQuery instead of $  :)

Comment: It means jQuery library is not included or it is not loaded..

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Wait, then why it is working on chrome?

Comment: The error is that jQuery is not defined, i tried with ctrl+F5 request but it's not working...

Comment: Do Ctrl + U check source and try to browse jQuery are you getting?

Comment: @user3900848 You are doing something from somewhere we cannot be aware of... Maybe you have an FF addon running redefining `$` or whatever. Is using `jQuery` fixing it? Are you sure it isn't a cache issue? Without knowing how do you debug it, we cannot really help you

Comment: @ParthTrivedi, source is https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js , it's official link from jQuery's site...

Everything is working in Chrome so the link can't be bad...

Comment: @A.Wolff yes may be addon issue.

Comment: @user3900848 Maybe FF handles protocol differently (not sure). So try using relative protocol if your site isn't running on https: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`. That's said, it should throw an error or at least warning in FF console if it was your issue

Comment: @A.Wolff, what is the versatile solution in such cases ? What if certain plugin redefine `$` and `jQuery` both ?

Comment: @A.Wolff, i tried ctrl+f5 couple more times and it worked. Everything is ok now, your answer is the right one. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RayonDabre Redefining `$` can be common but redefining `jQuery`, i don't think any plugin/addon would do that, but who knows... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found by [A.Wolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff)

Firefox started to work fine when i made couple of full requests(ctrl+f5) as [A.Wolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) suggested.

Comment: As a developer, We cannot expect the users of the website, to press ctrl+f5. Most of the users does not know this. We should give permanent solutions.

Answer (score 7):

You will get this error randomly based on loading time/different browsers. Because Root cause of this is that you are loading jquery.min.js from googleapis. Third party domain resources will get low priority than the local domain resources. "document ready" function statements will be triggered once the local domain resources are loaded. That is why you get this error.

**Permanent Solution**: Put jquery.min.js file in your server and call it from your  domain. this solution will work even if your page has load time issues and in any browser.

Comment: This will not always fix the issue. In my case, I already loaded jQuery from my server, but I included jQuery and my JS at the end of the DOM, which resulted in the same error. Putting it in the <head> helped a little bit, but it still fails ~10% of the time.

Comment: Followup: Including jQuery at multiple places seem to confuse firefox. This eliminated the last 10% for me.

Answer (score 2):

This problem persists even 3 years later. some people use jquery just for the $ function which is ridiculous. One could program it oneself.

`$ = document.getElementById` or `ByClass` there are many ways to search within the DOM and new ones that are appearing.

I had the problem of assigning functions for when the document was loaded which was solved by this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

use "jQuery" word (with out qutation) instead of $ in your code

Answer (score -1):

as suggested by [A.Wolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff). You need to press 'ctrl+f5' key. Sometimes it happens due to cache. Use 'ctrl+shift+delete' and clean the browser cache then run your code.