# Close button not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to design a search button. But close button is working fine in all browsers except Firefox. I have no clue why this is happening. Is there any other alternative way to achieve this?

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.searchBox = function(ev) {
    var $searchEl = $(".search-elem");
    var $placeHolder = $(".placeholder");
    var $sField = $("#search-field");


    if (ev === "open") {
      $searchEl.addClass("search-open");
    }

    if (ev === "close") {
      $searchEl.removeClass("search-open"), $placeHolder.removeClass(
        "move-up"
      ), $sField.val("");
    }

    var moveText = function() {
      $placeHolder.addClass("move-up");
    };

    $sField.focus(moveText);
    $placeHolder.on("click", moveText);

    $(".submit").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#search-field").keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $(".submit").prop("disabled", false);
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);


$(".search-btn").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).searchBox("open");
  e.preventDefault();
});
$(".close").on("click", function() {
  $(this).searchBox("close");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchdiv">
  <a href="#" class="search-btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
  <div class="search-box search-elem">
    <button class="close"> X </button>
    <div class="inner row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <label class="placeholder" for="search-field">Enter Search Key...</label>
        <input type="text" id="search-field">
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which part of the code is not working for you. Explain that..!

Comment: $(".close").on("click", function () {
        $(this).searchBox("close");
    });

Comment: Can you show us your log file from the developer console?

Comment: @aCSS - We know that `.searchBox("close")` is not working but in which part - `console.log`  and check whether you are getting inside the function and in your `if (ev === "close")` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Just now I tried the same in Firefox, and found it Jquery Lib was not downloaded by Firefox if I'm using JQuery CDN.
Solution to this: download jquery and save it on your server and access jquery lib from your server.

Comment: Please refer this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34286460/3953479) for more details.